# Seleccionar valores de dos diferentes tablas Java.Sql?

Tags: java, sql

Hola estoy intentando crear un método que me regresese un `String[]` con los datos de 2 tablas diferentes en este caso es la tabla `user` y la tabla `geolocation` , los datos de el usuario con su respectiva geolocación(ciudad,barrio,latitud,longitud).

Pero no logro crear una query "correcta".

```
static String[] getUserDataFromDb(JTextField id, JPasswordField pass) throws SQLException {

    String[] data = new String[9];

    Connection c = connectDB();

    Statement stmt = null;

    String query1 = "SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN geolocation ON user.userid = geolocation.userid" ;

    stmt = c.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query1);

    while (rs.next()) {

        data[0] = rs.getString("userid").trim();
        data[1] = rs.getString("name").trim();
        data[2] = rs.getString("surname").trim();
        data[3] = rs.getString("email").trim();
        data[4] = rs.getString("password").trim();          
        data[5] = rs.getString("city").trim();
        data[6] = rs.getString("district").trim();
        data[7] = rs.getString("latitude").trim();
        data[8] = rs.getString("longitudes").trim();    

    }

    stmt.close();
    c.close();

    return data;

}
```

Me regresa siempre un `error` ya que la query no esta bien escrita.

Las tablas son:

users:

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+
| name  | surname     |     email        |password|userid|   
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+
| jose  | aguilar     | jose@hotmail.com | 123    |jose23|
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+
```

geolocation:

```
    +-----------+-------------+-----------+---------+----------+
    | city      | district    | latitude  |longitude|   userid |
    +-------+-------------+-------------------------+----------+
    | su ciudad | su barrio   | 1.2       | -1.3    |   jose23 |
    +-----------+-------------+-----------+---------+----------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quizá sea porque en el resultado hay columnas duplicadas (userid). A mi siempre me aparecía ese error cuando había dos columnas con el mismo nombre en el resultado de la consulta.

Imagino que cuando quieres hacer el

```
data[0] = rs.getString("userid").trim();
```

Java no sabe a cuál columna te refieres, ya que hay dos

¿Puedes poner el error completo?

EDICION:

Has puesto user después del WHERE. Debería ser users. Para evitar este error por descuido y como buena práctica, deberías usar alias

```
SELECT * FROM users u INNER JOIN geolocation g ON u.userid = g.userid
```

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERRORE: errore di sintassi a o presso "."
  Posizione: 51
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
 at o

Comment: pues me viene el error el el punto "."

Comment: @BryanRomero Como dice esta respuesta, tienes columnas ambiguas en tu resultado final al usar `SELECT *`, deberías siempre listar en forma explícita las columnas que necesitas: `SELECT col1, col2, col3...`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN geolocation ON user.` has puesto user como alias y debe ser users, con una S

Comment: Has omitido una letra ;D

Comment: Te conviene utilizar el indice de la Columna rs.getString(1) por ejemplo

Comment: @GiancarloVenturaGranados Excelente observación. Es por eso que el op debería también acostumbrarse a usar alias de tablas

Comment: Oh vaya , si era eso , ahora la query funciona normalmente.

Comment: Si te ha funcionado marca la respuesta como correcta ;)

Answer (score 1):

Creo que has escrito mal el nombre de la tabla en el join:

```
ON user.userid = geolocation.userid
```

Debería ser:

```
ON users.userid=...
```